# Default behavior of a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got a custom control that is a textbox and two buttons inside a frame.

[image]

I'd like the frame to display the typical textbox border-behaviour. Currently, it just has a black border. **Is there a short way or will I need 200 lines of XAML?**

(I've found some examples e.g. the [ComboBoxStyles-Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx) from MS, but .. these do use 200 lines of XAML).

This is the style for the IntegerSpinControl:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type cc:IntegerSpinControl}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type cc:IntegerSpinControl}">

                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Right" x:Name="grid1"
                          Grid.Column="1"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RepeatButton Grid.Row="0"
                                      Grid.Column="1"
                                      Width="22"
                                      Height="10"
                                      Padding="0"
                                      BorderThickness="0"
                                      Command="{x:Static cc:IntegerSpinControl.IncreaseCommand}">
                                <RepeatButton.Content>
                                    <Rectangle Width="16"
                                           Height="5"
                                           Fill="{StaticResource brush.scroll.up}" />
                                </RepeatButton.Content>
                            </RepeatButton>
                            <RepeatButton Grid.Row="1"
                                      Grid.Column="1"
                                      Width="22"
                                      Height="10"
                                      Padding="0"
                                      BorderThickness="0"
                                      Command="{x:Static cc:IntegerSpinControl.DecreaseCommand}">
                                <RepeatButton.Content>
                                    <Rectangle Width="16"
                                           Height="5"
                                           Fill="{StaticResource brush.scroll.down}" />
                                </RepeatButton.Content>
                            </RepeatButton>
                        </Grid>
                        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                             BorderThickness="0"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                             Grid.Row="0"
                             Grid.Column="0"
                             Width="Auto"
                             Margin="0,0,1,0"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             IsReadOnly="True"
                             Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                            Path=FormattedValue,
                                            Mode=OneWay}" />

                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: share your custom control code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a control in the Extended WPF Toolkit that might be what you are looking for:

[IntegerUpDown Control](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IntegerUpDown&referringTitle=Home)

Maybe you can use that instead?

BTW: There are also a [`Decimal`](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DecimalUpDown&referringTitle=Home) and a [`Double`](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DoubleUpDown&referringTitle=Home) version in the toolkit.

That being said, if you have to use your own Custom Control you will have to create the `Templates` and `Styles` yourself, however you can probably copy heavily from the Windows defaults.